# Error when installing firebaseMessaging pod on ios

Tags: cocoapods

I'm compiling an app based on quasar with capacitor, I use push notifications so Firebase needs to be installed, I have another plugins so I use cocoapods, but when I run the compile process I got this

```
[!] Error installing FirebaseCore
        [!] /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk.git
        /var/folders/lb/_qw1jzyx4x591brsxfvqssyr0000gn/T/d20231122-25516-znczdh --template=
        --single-branch --depth 1 --branch CocoaPods-10.18.0
        
        Cloning into
        '/var/folders/lb/_qw1jzyx4x591brsxfvqssyr0000gn/T/d20231122-25516-znczdh'...
        warning: Could not find remote branch CocoaPods-10.18.0 to clone.
        fatal: Remote branch CocoaPods-10.18.0 not found in upstream origin
```

I tried to download the repos and target each pod with the path but I doesn't work

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Did you read the error?  ```Remote branch CocoaPods-10.18.0 not found in upstream origin```  I took a gander at that repo and there's no branch called that.  Where did you get the instructions of using that branch?

Comment: I followed all the steps on https://www.npmjs.com/package/@capacitor/push-notifications, I can not find where to modify the requested branch

Comment: From what I read, a Podfile?  This is the limit of my knowledge here.

Comment: Might be a transient networking issue. The tag is at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/releases/tag/CocoaPods-10.18.0